# Can you have two unwind segues from two different views return to the same view controller Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Noob working in Swift 5, and I am having problems setting up a second unwind segue that will return to a tableview.
[my setup here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdZZx.png)

In my original setup (first unwind), I put the unwind code (below) in the view I wished to return to, made the connection between the buttons to the exit and everything worked great. I had no problems with the first unwind:

```
@IBAction func unwindToThisViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
```

}

I then set up another view, accessible from the same tableview, but for some reason, I can not make a connection from the buttons to the Exit for the unwind.

My original thought was, since I am going back to the same view, I don't need to add another unwind func. That didn't work, so I added a second one, with a different name, that didn't work either. I cleaned the build folder, restarted Xcode, but nothing has allowed me to make a connection with this second unwind, which is making me think, is it not possible to unwind two segues to the same view?

Comment: It is definitely possible. If you can't select the unwind destination from the exit icon then it means that Xcode can't find any predecessor scenes with an unwind destination (the @IBaction function). Your setup looks straightforward, so I can't suggest off the top of my head why it isn't working, but I did want to reassure you that it is certainly possible.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11! I'll go back to see why it can't find the predecessor scenes. Thanks for letting me know what I am attempting is possible. Tis appreciated